# bind function to newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for any help.

I have a function. Inside this function, I create two buttons and assign two ids.

```
var content =

'<div>

'<div id="stationPopUpbtn">' +
        '<button id="createWave_updateStation" onclick="updateStationContent('+feature+')">Änderungen speichern</button>'+
        '<button id="createWave_deleteStation" onclick="deleteFeature('+feature+')">Station löschen</button>'+
    '</div>'+

'</div>';
```

later in the same function I want to do:

```
$('#_updateStation').bind('click', function(){ // stuff });
```

But it doesn't work. The content is added as part of a popup (OpenLayers) which in return is added to the map..

```
            var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                feature.id+"_popup",
                feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                new OpenLayers.Size(250, 100),
                content,
                null,   // anchor
                true,   // closeBox exists
                //closeBoxCallback
                function(){
                    feature.style.pointRadius = 20;
                    map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                }
            );
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).append(content);
//map.addControl(selectControl);
//selectControl.activate();
$(document).on('click', '#createWave_updateStation' ,function(){
    console.log("TES");
});
    $('#create_stationPopup').popup('open');
```

Comment: You have to bind it after you add it to the DOM.. so after you append the elements.. then bind the click event

Comment: thats what I do.. but there is no appending. my content is html that goes into a popup.

Comment: You didn't add it to the dom yet though.. It's just a string still.. so you have to add it somehow like element.html(content).. or element.append(content)

Comment: I could only add it to the document like $(document).append(content);

Comment: then after that line is where you bind the click event

Comment: see EDIT I made, still nothing. :´(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delegate the** Event to Static parent container. Doing so will attach the event listener after matching the child nodes..

```
$(document).on('click', '#_updateStation',function(){ // stuff }); version >= 1.7
```

I am delegating it to the document as I am not sure of your HTML structure..

So better to replace the document with a `Static Container..`

Also as of jQuery version **1.7** `.on()`  is the preferred method over `.bind()`

If you using version less than version **1.7** , you can use `.delegate` to attach the event

```
$(document).delegate('#_updateStation' ,'click',function(){ // stuff }); 
// version < 1.7
```

Comment: there is no static container. Everything is created "on the fly". I'm in Openlayers and create a popup, and inside that popup I have two buttons.. the next best thing would be the map itself. but my code does not get executed when the map loads..

Comment: Sure.. then Delegate it to the $(document)  or $('body')

Comment: `Doing so will attache the event to the element when the event bubbles up` - huh?

Comment: @sushath: im on >1.8.. but your first code does not work, its not fireing.

Comment: Are you appending the var content to your DOM

Comment: I could only add it to the document like $(document).append(content); But that doesnt do anything either